# Test if filesystem was cleanly unmounted

Tags: bash, filesystems, mount, fsck, vmdk

My problem is that a device might be mounted by a suspended `virtualbox` VM. If so I don't want to change the device under the virtualbox VM. The most obvious check is if the filesystem is cleanly unmounted. If so, it should be safe to mount it.
How can I test if a filesystem is cleanly unmounted without changing it?

The plan is to do something like

```
if cleanly_unmounted /dev/loop0
then mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/tmp
else echo UNCLEANLY MOUNTED, UNWISE TO MOUNT
```

I thought I could use `fsck -n` but it doesn't report any error even if the filesystem is currently mounted.

Comment: Which filesystem do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus I am using ext4.

Comment: `if [[ -d /mnt/tmp/lost+found ]]; then echo mounted; else echo "not mounted"; fi`

Comment: Odd, `tune2fs -l` claims that my currently mounted root directory is clean.

Comment: @Cyrus I guess the plan would be to do a temporary mount with `mount -t ext4 -o ro,noload` to mount `/mnt/tmp` without changing the filesystem under the VM?

Answer (score 0):

[MMP](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Multiple_Mount_Protection) - multiple mount protection - should do the trick.

You need to enable it on the filesystem:

```
tune2fs -M mmp <dev>
```

And then you can use `e2mmpstatus` to check if it's already mounted.

Note that you need to manually call `e2mmpstatus` to check if it's mounted before calling `mount`. Otherwise, linux will be happy to mount it twice and ruin the filesystem.

Example:

```
> truncate --size 1000000 /tmp/test.img
> mkfs.ext4 /tmp/test.img
> tune2fs -O mmp /tmp/test.img
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Multiple mount protection has been enabled with update interval 5s.
> mkdir /tmp/mnt
> e2mmpstatus /tmp/test.img; echo $?
e2mmpstatus: it is safe to mount '/tmp/test.img', MMP is clean
0
> mount /tmp/test.img /tmp/mnt
> e2mmpstatus /tmp/test.img; echo $?
e2mmpstatus: MMP: device currently active while trying to open /tmp/test.img
e2mmpstatus: MMP last updated by 'noon' on Tue Jul 20 12:13:25 2021
1
```